# Handle git submodules to make a "snapshot" of current state

Tags: git, yocto

I have a Yocto project, where some folders are clones of git repositories.
Now I need to create a repository of the "snapshot" of the current `layers` directory.
Example:

```
layers/
    .git // <--- my new repository
    meta-openembedded/  // <--- it's a repo
        .git
    meta-qt5/           // <--- it's a repo
        .git
```

In my "layers" repository, I'm not interested to maintain the "submodules" as git repositories. This is because I changed some files and I'm not really sure if I can commit them (these repositories of course aren't mine!).
I tried to add `.git/` in `.gitignore` but it still sees the directories as submodules and doesn't add them to my repository:

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

      new file: .gitignore
      new file: meta-openembedded
      new file: meta-qt5
      ...

    Changes not staged for commit:
      (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
      (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
      (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   meta-openembedded (modified content)
        modified:   meta-qt5 (modified content)
```

Adding the directory doesn't work (they are already there, by the way).
Of course a rude way is to delete the `.git` direcory... but I hope there's a way to tell git to just ignore them.

Anyway, I also tried to commit my changes to one of the submodules, but it still won't add it:

```
Changes not staged for commit:

    modified: meta-openembedded (new commits)
```

Comment: You doing it wrong, editing upstream layers is probably not a good idea. Just make a new repostories for meta-obenembedded, meta-qt and change the git remote.

Comment: @FlorianBerndl, if I understand correctly I need to remove the `.git` directories and than issue some `git init` to create the new repositories? Then it would enough to remove the git dirs and rely on my top-level repo.

Comment: 1.) go to github  2.) create new EMPTY repository meta-openembedded 3.) cd meta-openembedded 4.) git remote rename origin upstream 5.) git remote add <yourgithubrepourl> 6.) git push . Now you have a copy of the git repo ( fork). Do modifications as your want and repeat that for all upstream repos like your want. For using multiple git repositores I can recommend the repo tool.

Comment: This should be an answer, rather a comment, indeed!

Answer (score 2):

For such stuff I prefeere an different workflow. Create an new empty repository ( e.g meta-openembedded) on github or your service of choice.

```
git clone <yourrepo>
cd meta-openembedded 
git remote rename origin upstream 
git remote add <yourgithubrepourl> 
git push
git checkout -b <myfeaturebranch>
```

Now you have a copy of the git repository ( fork). Do modifications as your want and repeat that for all upstream repos like your want. You should work on your feature branch and you can pull from the original using:

```
git pull <remote>
```

For using multiple git repositores I can recommend the repo tool. [repo](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/)